# CSS of one component is conflicting with another component using angular 12

Tags: html, css, angular, angular12

angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "./src/assets/css/base.css",
    "./src/assets/css/dashboard.css",
    "src/styles.css"
],
```

styles.css

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~assets/css/base.css";
@import "~assets/css/dashboard.css";
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './component/front/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './component/admin/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './component/admin/profile/profile.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './component/front/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path:'', component:HomeComponent },
  { path:'admin/dashboard', component:DashboardComponent },
  { path:'admin/profile', component:ProfileComponent },
  { path:'**', component:PagenotfoundComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image]

In the above image I have two module inside component folder i.e. `front` and `admin` for `front` I have `base.css` and for `admin` I have `dashboard.css` and when I serve ng command the layout of `front` folder component disturb but when I remove `dashboard.css` from `styles.css` then it working fine. Similarly In case of admin folder component. So, How can I manage this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: as my understanding you need to understand `View encapsulation` topic in angular. here is link for it https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

Comment: just import `dashboard.css ` in dashboard component css file and `base.css` in front component css file, and read above provided link so you better understand.

Comment: Actully, I had tried `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` but nothing happen @MohitSharma

Comment: can you provide some `stackblitz` so i can see

Comment: You'll need to provide the relevant html and css files, you can remove the folder structure and app-routing module since both are irrelevant. Is there a reason you're using global style sheets instead of component style sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Any `css` that's imported, or declared, in the global `styles.css` is considered global e.g. last style declared takes precedence

You can add the styles to the `css` associated with and imported by the components, or else continue using the global styles but add more specific selectors

Comment: when I import `dashboard.css` in `dashboard.component.css` file then `sidebar` has been hide. I have also create common file for `sidebar`, `top` as header and `bottom` as footer and call inside `dashboard.component.html` using selector. Where `sidebar` are not visible.